# Formatted math in python source parsing with doxygen?

Tags: latex, doxygen, mathjax

I'm a bit stuck getting doxygen to do what I want. Which is simply having formatted math in the comment string. Neither html or latex works. MATHJAX is enabled. I'm probably missing something really trivial.

Python source:

```
class te1:
    def aaa(self):
        pass

    def bbb(self):
        """\f[ f(x) = e^x \f]"""
        pass
```

I run doxygen in mostly default configuration, just setting `USE_MATHJAX=YES`

Doxygen version 1.8.14, running latex version of MacTex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class te1:
    def aaa(self):
        pass

    def bbb(self):
        """!\f[ f(x) = e^x \f]"""
        pass
```

Note the `!` after `"""`.

Comment: Amazing, works! Is there a place in the documentation where I could have found this myself? Cannot find it here at least https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/formulas.html

Comment: It should have been documented here: http://www.doxygen.org/manual/docblocks.html#pythonblocks but to my own surprise it isn't!