# Documenting math formulas as comments in python code using Doxygen

Tags: python, formula, doxygen

my question is an extension of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340133/formatted-math-in-python-source-parsing-with-doxygen/49347009#49347009), and what i want is Doxygen to output the math formulas and text that are in the same comment line of my python source code. Let's take the following example:

```
# Create homogeneous probability matrix from the colors matrix
def create_probability_map(colors_map):
    """!\f$(x_1,y_1)\f$"""
    pass
```

When I run the above code, Doxygen outputs the [correct math formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUz24.png), as expected.
However, if I add some text before the math formula:

```
# Create homogeneous probability matrix from the colors matrix
def create_probability_map(colors_map):
    """Formula is: !\f$(x_1,y_1)\f$"""
    pass
```

The  output is not as expected. **Does anyone know how to fix this?**

[image: output is not as expected]

While trying other several combinations, I found out that Doxygen [outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz5IK.png) the correct comment if the text is after the math formula, as follows:

```
# Create homogeneous probability matrix from the colors matrix
def create_probability_map(colors_map):
    """!\f$(x_1,y_1)\f$ is the formula"""
    pass
```

P.S: I also found it strange that supposedly Doxygen can't process math formulas on Python, as stated on the [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#pythonblocks) (specifically in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb6QU.png)). Is the documentation out of date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with doxygen 1.8.18 the following code:

```
## \file

# Create homogeneous probability matrix from the colors matrix
def create_probability_map1(colors_map):
    """!\f$(x_1,y_1)\f$"""
    pass

# Create homogeneous probability matrix from the colors matrix
def create_probability_map2(colors_map):
    """Formula is: !\f$(x_2,y_2)\f$"""
    pass

# Create homogeneous probability matrix from the colors matrix
def create_probability_map3(colors_map):
    """!\f$(x_3,y_3)\f$ is the formula"""
    pass

# Create homogeneous probability matrix from the colors matrix
def create_probability_map4(colors_map):
    """!Formula is: \f$(x_4,y_4)\f$ is the formula"""
    pass
```

with default doxygen configuration settings, this results in:

[image]

This looks all OK to me the doc strings with`"""!` are seen as doxygen comments and with just `"""` are seen as verbatim / code (as also shown in the mentioned link in the question).

Comment: Perfect, so the trick was actually starting the comment with """! instead on only """. Thanks a lot, that really helped! :)